# Is Classic ADO still viable for a mixed managed/unmanaged App?

Tags: ado.net, ado, unmanaged

We have a complex architecture with much logic in unmanaged code that needs database access.

Currently this is via ODBC drivers and MFC classes and we're considering the issues of migrating our abstraction layer to use ADO or ADO.Net. In the latter case we'd have to be pushing database logic back up into the .Net layer. I'm trying to decide if the pain of invoking the database via .Net callbacks is offset by the improvements in ADO.Net.

The [Wikipedia comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_ADO_and_ADO.NET) was interesting although I'm not sure I believe all the points in the comparison table (eg: does ADO.Net always use XML to pass data?).

A [2005 comparison](http://www.rt.db.erau.edu/655s08/655webADO/index.html) shows ADO.Net performing dramatically faster.

Microsoft's [guide to ADO.Net for ADO programmers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973217.aspx) suggests we will gain much from going to ADO.Net especially the way that data is available in native (.Net) types rather than solely through OLEAutomation's Variant.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> eg: does ADO.Net always use XML to pass data?
> ```

No. Sounds like idiot information in wikipedia then.

2 choices. First, I would REALLY get rid of ODBC - and move at least to OleDb driver wise. If possible (tell me - I have a .NET app using an ODBC driver to call a JDBC ddriver to call a third party application server).

Now, you can go both ways - ADO on both sides, managed ADO.NET and expose from the NET layer - but this is really not a programmer decision, it is an architectural thing that should be seen in the major context.
I would possibly go for a .NET layer, possibly with at the same time an OData exposure layer, and try to consume that from the unmanaged layer.